# Deterministic keys with one-way operation

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

BIP 0032 "Security Implications" states

> One weakness that may not be immediately obvious, is that knowledge of
>   a parent extended public key plus any non-hardened private key
>   descending from it is equivalent to knowing the parent extended
>   private key (and thus every private and public key descending from
>   it).

From what I understand, the weakness is due to the reversible nature of the operation on extended public key (addition). Wouldn't it be possible to address this by using a one-way function like hashing instead of addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a one-way hash function (ie like hashing ECDSA public key with SHA256/RIPEMD160 into a hex public key) then how can you employ hierarchical deterministic functioning?

You can't. The whole point here is that if you lose your private key for a grandchild public key you can get it back again with the parent key. A two-way hashing function obfuscating the data would work but that's basically what's already in place.

Comment: can you help me understand why hashing wouldn't be deterministic? I'm guessing something like sha256(extended_private_key, offset) where offset is 1...n could result in n deterministic keys

Comment: I may be wrong, but if the hash has no predictable outcome, then adding an offset to the random number is just saying `random hashed output + offset`, or more simply (since we ignore the random part) `offset`, which is what we have already with HD wallets. Hashing the offset is the only way but then how do you get it back? If there's a take home point it's that there is no way to predict a hashed output, and if there were, the encryption would be poor. Hashed output would be impossible to detect the offset added to it.